# Parse terminfo u6 string

Tags: terminal, console, xterm, ncurses, terminfo

Looking at [terminfo](http://linux.die.net/man/5/terminfo) and *Parameterized Strings*.

Some examples from `infocmp -1 xterm`:

- `cud=\E[%p1%dB`, given argument `13`:

  - `\E` =>`<ESC>`
  - `[` => `[`
  - `%p1` PUSH parameter 1 *(13)* onto stack
  - `%d` POP and print from stack as signed decimal => `13`

    - Result: `<ESC>[13B`
- `csr=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr`, given arguments `13, 16`:

  - `\E` =>`<ESC>`
  - `[` => `[`
  - `%i` Increment parameter 1 and 2: ++13, ++16 gives 14, 17
  - `%p1` PUSH parameter 1 *(14)* onto stack.
  - `%d` POP and print from stack as signed decimal. => `14`
  - `;` => `;`
  - `%p2` PUSH parameter 2 *(17)* onto stack.
  - `%d` POP and print from stack as signed decimal. => `17`
  - `r` => `r`

    - Result: `<ESC>14;17r`

But, ... how to read this one?

- `u6=\E[%i%d;%dR`

After processing `\E[%i` we have `<ESC>[` and incremented parameter 1 and 2 (if any). But stack is empty. Should not the two `%d`'s pop and print two numbers from stack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The absence of a **`%p`** marker is a quirk of ncurses: the terminfo compiler ([**tic**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tic.1m.html)) recognizes either terminfo (which uses **`%p1`** to *mark* parameters) or termcap (which relies upon *convention* for the parameters).   That would be a legal *termcap* expression.  Since **tic** knows how to process a termcap expression, the string shown is "close enough" that there was no need to translate it further.

You can see what ncurses does using [**`tput`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html), e.g.,

```
tput u6 40 50
```

gives (note the reversal of parameters)

```
^[[51;41R
```

If the expression were given as

```
u6=\E[%i%p2%d;%p1%dR
```

it would have the same result.

The u6-u9 capabilities are an early *extension* documented in ncurses's [terminal database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_T_E_R_M_I_N_A_L__T_Y_P_E__D_E_S_C_R_I_P_T_I_O_N_S__S_O_U_R_C_E__F_I_L_E):

```
# INTERPRETATION OF USER CAPABILITIES
#
# The System V Release 4 and XPG4 terminfo format defines ten string
# capabilities for use by applications, <u0>...<u9>.   In this file, we use
# certain of these capabilities to describe functions which are not covered
# by terminfo.  The mapping is as follows:
#
#       u9      terminal enquire string (equiv. to ANSI/ECMA-48 DA)
#       u8      terminal answerback description
#       u7      cursor position request (equiv. to VT100/ANSI/ECMA-48 DSR 6)
#       u6      cursor position report (equiv. to ANSI/ECMA-48 CPR)
#
# The terminal enquire string <u9> should elicit an answerback response
# from the terminal.  Common values for <u9> will be ^E (on older ASCII
# terminals) or \E[c (on newer VT100/ANSI/ECMA-48-compatible terminals).
#
# The cursor position request (<u7>) string should elicit a cursor position
# report.  A typical value (for VT100 terminals) is \E[6n.
#
# The terminal answerback description (u8) must consist of an expected
# answerback string.  The string may contain the following scanf(3)-like
# escapes:
#
#       %c      Accept any character
#       %[...]  Accept any number of characters in the given set
#
# The cursor position report (<u6>) string must contain two scanf(3)-style
# %d format elements.  The first of these must correspond to the Y coordinate
# and the second to the %d.  If the string contains the sequence %i, it is
# taken as an instruction to decrement each value after reading it (this is
# the inverse sense from the cup string).  The typical CPR value is
# \E[%i%d;%dR (on VT100/ANSI/ECMA-48-compatible terminals).
#
# These capabilities are used by tack(1m), the terminfo action checker
# (distributed with ncurses 5.0).
```

Checking that last comment, [tack](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/tack.html) exercises `u8` and `u9` but does nothing with `u6` and `u7`.

The extension was added [early in 1995](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#t1995022219_27_34):

```
# 9.3.4 (Wed Feb 22 19:27:34 EST 1995):
#       * Added correct acsc/smacs/rmacs strings for vt100 and xterm.
#       * Added u6/u7/u8/u9 capabilities.
#       * Added PCVT entry.
```

and while it is included in several entries for *completeness* (not many: there are 16 occurrences in 18,699 lines of `terminfo.src`), there are no well-known users of the feature.  In fact, there is one place in ncurses where it *could* have been written to use it (some ifdef'd debugging code in the [`tty_update.c`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/546c101eb3f7b716cbf59e496122e6c2a25c50f8/ncurses/tty/tty_update.c#L161) file), but that uses hard-coded escape sequences (marked as "ANSI compatible").

The reason for the absence of users would be:

- inverting an arbitrary terminfo expression is harder than it may seem
- xterm and similar terminals interpret these escape sequences

In [ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm), these are (u7) *DSR* (device status report) and (u6) *CPR* (active position report).

Comment: For what it's worth, the [direct mode](https://github.com/dankamongmen/notcurses/blob/master/src/lib/direct.c) of Notcurses uses `u7` extensively, including in `ncdirect_cursor_yx()`, and `ncdirect_cursor_move_yx()`. I wasn't aware of `u6`, though, and have been running a baroque algorithm to determine cursor report inversion and the need for decrement (see `detect_cursor_inversion()`); I will switch to `u6`, and hopefully eliminate this code.

Answer (score 3):

Ahha.

It is a *special entry* in the database. It gives the [*respond format*](https://gist.github.com/ihodes/6583556#file-termtypes-ti-L159) to `u7`.

The response is `<ESC>[Y;XR` as in Y=row and X=column.

If  `u6` has `%i`, one should *decrement* the responded values.

Example:

- `u6=\E[%i%d;%dR`
- `u7=\E[6n`

Send `u7`.

- Response for example: `\E[48;13R`.
- Result:

  - `Y = 48 - 1 = 47`
  - `X = 13 - 1 = 12`.